# .htaccess to nginx converter

Tags: .htaccess, nginx-config

Please help how to convert below .htaccess code to nginx

```
RewriteEngine on
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

need this for OAuth, but after putting the credential authorization is not success.

I think this should come under nginx location block, but not sure.

Comment: You shouldn't _need_ to convert this to Nginx, since this directive is a workaround for an issue on Apache/CGI. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71336833/369434) to [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326384/can-anyone-help-to-change-this-htaccess-rule-to-nginx). Btw, `RewriteEngine` has nothing to do with `SetEnvIf`. (Unable to flag as a dupe since the dupe question has no upvoted/accepted answers.)